# Search for Selected Text & Format into Multiple Tables With Headers

Tags: vba, ms-word

There is text in the middle of a long MS Word document to be converted to multiple tables each with a header.

I have written code where I select the header sentence, run a macro and it gets formatted.
Then I can select another section of text, run another macro and it gets converted to a table and formatted.
I do this for each header/table combo.

I would like to select all the text, run one macro and it gets converted/formatted into multiple headers and tables.

I was thinking of putting unique characters (like the @@@ and ### in the example below) at the start of each header and each table section.
I'm struggling with how to move through the selected text, find the unique characters to act on and move to the next unique character.

If you have an idea other than using these unique characters that is welcome too.

```
A whole bunch of text.
@@@This is a header
###This is text to format & convert to a table
@@@This is a header
###This is text to format & convert to a table
@@@This is a header
###This is text to format & convert to a table
@@@This is a header
###This is text to format & convert to a table
A whole bunch of text.
```

Code that converts the selection to a table.

```vb
Sub textToTable()

    Selection.ConvertToTable Separator:=wdSeparateByDefaultListSeparator, _
        NumColumns:=5, NumRows:=6, AutoFitBehavior:=wdAutoFitFixed
    With Selection.Tables(1)
        .Style = "Table Grid"
        .ApplyStyleHeadingRows = True
        .ApplyStyleLastRow = False
        .ApplyStyleFirstColumn = True
        .ApplyStyleLastColumn = False
    End With

    Selection.Tables(1).Rows(3).Cells.Merge
    Selection.Tables(1).Rows(4).Cells.Merge
    Selection.Tables(1).Rows(5).Cells.Merge
    Selection.Tables(1).Rows(6).Cells.Merge

    Selection.Tables(1).Rows(1).Shading.Texture = wdTextureNone
    Selection.Tables(1).Rows(1).Shading.ForegroundPatternColor = wdColorAutomatic
    Selection.Tables(1).Rows(1).Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = -603923969

    Selection.Tables(1).Rows(3).Shading.Texture = wdTextureNone
    Selection.Tables(1).Rows(3).Shading.ForegroundPatternColor = wdColorAutomatic
    Selection.Tables(1).Rows(3).Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = -603923969

    Selection.Tables(1).Rows(5).Shading.Texture = wdTextureNone
    Selection.Tables(1).Rows(5).Shading.ForegroundPatternColor = wdColorAutomatic
    Selection.Tables(1).Rows(5).Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = -603923969
    
    Selection.Tables(1).Rows(1).Select
    Selection.Font.Bold = True
    Selection.Tables(1).Rows(3).Select
    Selection.Font.Bold = True
    Selection.Tables(1).Rows(5).Select
    Selection.Font.Bold = True

    ' Remove return characters
    Selection.Tables(1).Rows(6).Select
    tempString = Selection.Range.Text
    Selection.Range.Text = Left(tempString, Len(tempString) - 5)
End Sub
```

Code that formats the header.

```vb
Sub Heading()    
    Selection.Font.Italic = True
    Selection.Range.Font.TextColor.RGB = RGB(97, 146, 0)
    temp = Selection.Range.Text
    Selection.Range.Text = Right(temp, Len(temp) - 1)     
End Sub
```

This is what the text looks like before I run the two macros. This text could be repeated 1 to n times in my Word document:
[image]

This is what my final formatted table looks like in Word:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@@@` is the maker of start line. The code automatically convert caption header (one paragraph) and table (six paragraphs).

Note: There could be more than one sentence in a row (cell). But it should be in a paragraph.

```vb
Option Explicit
Sub SearchTab()
    Application.DefaultTableSeparator = "*"
    Selection.HomeKey unit:=wdStory
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = "@@@"
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindStop
        .Format = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
        Do While .Execute
            With Selection
                .Delete
                .Expand wdParagraph
                .Font.Italic = True
                .Range.Font.TextColor.RGB = RGB(97, 146, 0)
                .MoveDown unit:=wdParagraph
                .MoveDown unit:=wdParagraph, Count:=6, Extend:=wdExtend
                Call textToTable
                .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
            End With
        Loop
    End With
End Sub
Sub textToTable()
    Dim tempString As String, i As Integer
    Selection.ConvertToTable Separator:=wdSeparateByDefaultListSeparator, _
        NumColumns:=5, NumRows:=6, AutoFitBehavior:=wdAutoFitFixed
    With Selection.Tables(1)
        .Style = "Table Grid"
        .ApplyStyleHeadingRows = True
        .ApplyStyleLastRow = False
        .ApplyStyleFirstColumn = True
        .ApplyStyleLastColumn = False
        For i = 1 To .Rows.Count
            If i > 2 Then .Rows(i).Cells.Merge
            If Int(i / 2) <> i / 2 Then
                .Rows(i).Shading.Texture = wdTextureNone
                .Rows(i).Shading.ForegroundPatternColor = wdColorAutomatic
                .Rows(i).Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = -603923969
                .Rows(i).Range.Font.Bold = True
            End If
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: I added a screenshot of my final table in Word in the original post.  What I call a 'header' is not a part of the table.  It is the green text above the table.  So in Word, I manually highlight that text, run the macro Heading then manually highlight a bunch of other text and run the macro textToTable.  My table will always be 5 columns and 6 rows.

Comment: Please share what is look like before converting table.

Comment: Done. Screenshot of original data is added to my post.

Comment: There are more than one sentences (paragraphs) in a cell (row). Is `textToTable()` capable to automatically covert it?

Comment: Ahh, you did identify an issue.  It works on multiple sentences, but not when there are multiple paragraphs with return characters in there.  I will need to find a fix for that.

Comment: I have update the code which can handle multiple sentences in a paragraph. Please let me know if you figure out the logic of multiple paragraphs.